# Powershell Remote Variable Interpolation

Tags: powershell, scope, remoting

I am having trouble passing variables into remote sessions. From the about_Remote_Variable help page, I know that I can do:

```
$localLog = "Windows Powershell"

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
    Get-WinEvent -LogName $using:localLog | select -First 5;
}
```

And this works well enough.  But then if I do the following:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {
    $remoteLog = $using:localLog;
    Get-WinEvent -LogName $remoteLog | select -First 5;
}
```

I get the error:

```
A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, 
Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, 
the Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UsingWithoutInvokeCommand
    + PSComputerName        : myComputer
```

Why does this fail?  I need to understand this because in my real script I am trying to pass many more variables and do more complicated things.

Thanks, bob

Comment: Perhaps you are running into a bug.  Your second example works for me on the PowerShell v5.  Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: really?  The local machine is a 2012R2 running v4 and the client is Win8.1 with v5.

Comment: I was going from v5 (Win10) to v5 (Win8.1).